# Can't find com.sun.jdi in Jboss

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jboss, jdi

Hey Everyone! 
            I keep getting ClassNotFound exception on Sun.Jdi in the Jboss EAP 7. It is used by a [HotswapAgent](http://hotswapagent.org/) thus I want to know how to add com.sun.jdi to the Jboss either via module loader or someway else.

```
    18:16:48,158 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-634) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jdi/request/EventRequest
18:16:48,158 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-634)    at org.hotswap.agent.plugin.hotswapper.HotswapperCommand.hotswap(HotswapperCommand.java:30)
18:16:48,158 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-634)    ... 6 more
18:16:48,158 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-634) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jdi.request.EventRequest from [Module "deployment.dcs.war" from Service Module Loader]
18:16:48,158 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-634)    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
18:16:48,158 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-634)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
18:16:48,158 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-634)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
18:16:48,158 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-634)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
18:16:48,158 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-634)    ... 7 more
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else has had this issue, you need tools.jar to be loaded as a module in JBoss/Wildfly. 
I found the tools.jar in the c:\program files\java\{JDK folder}\lib folder. 
Remember to add the dependency to the project.